# "npx create-react-app my-app" when i run this command by default it support NPM Package Manger?

Tags: reactjs, npm, yarnpkg, npx, yarn-lock.json

"npx create-react-app my-app" This command create a react application with the NPM package manager by default.

AND

"npx create-react-app my-app --use-yarn" This command does also the same as the above command.

What to do if we want yarn as default when I run the npx command?

Please help me out...

I try both the command which I mentioned in the problem statement.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/#yarn)

```
yarn create react-app my-app
```

Comment: when I go to this site "https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app" it is showing that this "npx create-react-app my-app" command install yarn but it is not in window.

Comment: how can i use same command to install yarn

Comment: According to [this](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/#selecting-a-package-manager) the gif is wrong